# Apache/SSL: (70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Figured upgrading on a long weekend was a smart move... Now I'm stuck.

The server is spitting out this error (loglevel info):  "(70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed" when using the Microsoft API to retrieve data from a web server.

If I use the cURL binding, everything is fine.  Trouble is, most people have the former.

Does anyone know what "(70014)End of file found: SSL input filter read failed" and how to fix it?  ... Fast!

Comment: Did you every find a solution to this? I am experiencing this same exact issue.

Comment: If you use curl -sslv3 https://host/ does it work?  Do you get the same result with curl --tlsv1 ?   Also, in your apache conf (httpd.conf and all the files in conf.d) grep -i protocol *.conf

Comment: Check out this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/633787/ssl-input-filter-read-failed-apache-and-443