# "SSL input filter read failed" Apache and 443

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, https

I have a little problem with my apache conf. When I read the error log, here is what I can see:

```
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 1 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 6 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 10 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 15 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
[client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01964: Connection to child 18 established (server www.mywebsite.com:443)
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
(70014)End of file found: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

And sometimes, this one:

```
 (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client xxx.xxx.xx.xx] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

I don't know actually ... so my website is full HTTP, except two page in HTTPS. So here is my virtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias img.mywebsite.com
    ServerAdmin xxx
    DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www/public
    <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/>
        Options Indexes Multiviews FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 http://www.google.com/
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/public/resource/private/>
        Require all denied
        ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mywebsite.com/
    </Directory>
    <Location "/robots.txt">
            Require all granted
    </Location>

    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mywebsite.com
        DocumentRoot /home/mywebsite/www/public
            <Directory /home/mywebsite/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
            </Directory>
        LogLevel info
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mywebsite_access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile ./mywebsite.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile ./mywebsite.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile ./intermediate.crt
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So, where I've done a mistake? I can't find it out ... Can you help me?

thank :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem in Apache 2.4.7.  It's not a question of SNI support.  Nor is "just lower the log level" a real answer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I read that Apache doesn't support SSL on name-based virtual host, only on IP based Virtual Hosts. So I changed it:

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
```

by:

```
 <VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
```

For now, it seems to work, I don't know if it's the good solution, but I don't have any error ...

Comment: Indeed, the Apache recommendations and sample configuration is [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts).

Comment: The same problem in apache-2.4 is not fixed by this solution :(

Comment: You may need to add multiple IPs if you have more than one hostname you're trying to serve over SSL.

Comment: Apache is supposed to support SSL on multiple VirtualHosts using the same IP "using 2.2.12 or later web server, built with 0.9.8j or later OpenSSL" with clients newer than IE8/WinXP. This is called SNI. There's discussion [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#vhosts2). I have it working, but these pesky log messages are everywhere!

Comment: It's not working for me.

Comment: Same. My Apache install should support SNI, and there is no problem accessing the multiple SSL VHosts on the server--each one provides the correct certificate, so SNI is by definition working.  Yet these log messages persist, and must have another cause.

Answer (score 0):

One more requirement is add the following line to the end of your VirtualHost SSL port 443 directives blocks

```
SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

As stated [here](http://wiki.indie-it.com/index.php?title=Apache_HTTP_Server#HOWTO:_Fix_Error:_The_timeout_specified_has_expired:_SSL_input_filter_read_failed):

Comment: This is poor advice.  Adding `nokeepalive` to your server configuration could seriously degrade performance, and is only needed for older versions of MSIE at the most.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/26/https-and-keep-alive-connections/

Answer (score 0):

for me ridiculously simple solution for this error as follows (this error shown up after adding files/folders as root):

```
chown www-data: /var/www -R
chmod 755 /var/www -R
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for me the reason was that <VirtualHost *:443> has been defined in 2 different config files in Apache. Once in the SSL.conf and the second time in the .conf file I was adding.
Once I removed reference to <VirtualHost *:443> (with its closing argument) from my second file everything worked.