# Permissions issue after update of webapplication (Drupal)

Tags: apache-2.2

I just upgraded Drupal 8 to 8.1.10 and I am facing a problem that I do not understand.

I know that Drupal rewrites permission and I do not use .htaccess files. I have folders that I must access (and deny only a subfolder). In my apache config, there is:

```
<Directory /var/www/webservice>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/webservice/restricted>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

That allowed me to access all content of webservice folder except restricted subforlder. This folder is not part of Drupal. I have restarted my apache server, I have enlarged user permission on files to 775. Nothing changes, I can access everything as usual except a php script that is in the webservice folder.

Why am I receiving a 403 forbidden error for this file, it used to work before I updated Drupal?

**Update:**

Before update I had a SSL problem, that I fixed reading [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/633787/ssl-input-filter-read-failed-apache-and-443). Now, Apache Error Log says:

```
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.410323 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 2384] [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH01964: Connection to child 3 established (server www.domain.com:443)
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.410656 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 2384] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2096): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.domain.com found
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.410673 2016] [core:debug] [pid 2384] protocol.c(1891): [client x.y.z.w:1172] select protocol from , choices=h2,spdy/3.1,http/1.1 for server www.domain.com
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.410684 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 2384] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2096): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername www.domain.com found
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.442414 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 2384] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2023): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.451305 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 2384] ssl_engine_kernel.c(354): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 3 (server www.domain.com:443)
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.451784 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2384] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:06.451800 2016] [authz_core:debug] [pid 2384] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:11.456991 2016] [ssl:info] [pid 2384] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
[Mon Oct 03 11:18:11.457095 2016] [ssl:debug] [pid 2384] ssl_engine_io.c(1016): [client x.y.z.w:1172] AH02001: Connection closed to child 3 with standard shutdown (server www.domain.com:443)
```

when I try to reach PHP script:

```
x.y.z.w - - [03/Oct/2016:11:18:06 +0000] "GET /webservice/inline.php HTTP/1.1" 403 752 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
```

After SSL error fixed I then have upgraded Drupal and I get it again (misfixed maybe). But this is not an error, this is info level. Is this logger noise or does it point to my problem?

Comment: What does the apachelog say ? Have you deleted the new .htaccess file ?

Comment: @rémy added Apache Log, no I have not removed, I just do not use .htaccess file since I have access to apache.conf. I have checked, after updated ./vendors/.htaccess are identical.

Comment: Apache will only fail to log something in the error log on a 403 under certain conditions. 1) You have the log level down so that virtually nothing gets logged. 2) You have  `RewriteRule` that uses the `[F]` flag 3) Your application generated the 403. You have no errors in the error log, so the most likely thing is Drupal is generating the 403 error.

Comment: I dropped Drupal and everything went fine. Was the product that mess my configuration after updating. Thank you